# Empty node workflow state on node after programmatically saving

Tags: nodes, workflows

I have saved a node programmatically, in the following way:

```
  $node_storage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node');
  foreach ($entity_ids as $id) {
    $node = $node_storage->load($id);
    if (!$node) {
      continue;
    }
    $node->set('field_tags', $new_tid);
    $node->save();
```

After saving the node I am trying to edit it and I am getting the follow error upon submit.

```
InvalidArgumentException: The state '' does not exist in workflow 'draft' in Drupal\workflows\Entity\Workflow->getState()
```

I believe that this means that my node has no state.

How could I set the node's state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a code for creating a node and indicating its status, maybe it would help:

`<?php
// add node properties
$newNode = (object) NULL;
$newNode->type = '{NODE_TYPE}';
$newNode->title = '{NODE_TITLE}'
$newNode->uid = {USER_ID};
$newNode->created = strtotime("now");
$newNode->changed = strtotime("now");
$newNode->status = 1;
$newNode->comment = 0;
$newNode->promote = 0;
$newNode->moderate = 0;
$newNode->sticky = 0;`

`// add CCK field data
$newNode->field_{YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_1}[0]['value'] = '{DATA_1}';
$newNode->field_{YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_2}[0]['value'] = '{DATA_2}';`

`// save node
node_save($newNode);
?>`